# Removing SKSpriteNode with touch detection

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to remove a node generated by this function by touching it.

```
func cuadrado(){

    var cuadradoRojo = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "cuadradoRojo")
    cuadradoRojo.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: cuadradoRojo.size.width)
    cuadradoRojo.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    cuadradoRojo.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.cuadrado.rawValue
    cuadradoRojo.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.colorAzul.rawValue | BodyType.colorRojo.rawValue
    cuadradoRojo.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0

    var actionArray3:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()




    if gameOver == false{


        let minX = circuloAzul.size.width/2

        let maxX = self.frame.size.width - circuloAzul.size.width/2

        let rangeX = maxX - minX


        let position:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random()) % CGFloat(rangeX) + CGFloat(minX)

        cuadradoRojo.position = CGPointMake(position, self.frame.size.height + cuadradoRojo.size.height)

            addChild(cuadradoRojo)

        let minDuration = 3


        let duration = Int(minDuration)

        func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent){
            for touch: AnyObject in touches {
                let location = (touch as UITouch).locationInNode(self)
                if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.cuadradoRojo {
                   cuadradoRojo.removeFromParent()

                }
            }
        }

        actionArray3.addObject(SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(position, -cuadradoRojo.size.height), duration: NSTimeInterval(duration)))


        cuadradoRojo.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actionArray3))

    }
```

It runs perfectly but it doesn't detect the touch, if I put the touches function outside it detects the touch, but the game crashes.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Where is this function declared? The code in the touchesBegan method needs to be placed in the scene's overriden touchesBegan method

Comment: i can't use override  inside an other function it gives me error. I declared it in the override func touchesBegan  method but the node did weird things and the game crashed

Comment: The touchesBegan method should not be existing inside the cuadrado() method at all, but outside in the scene

Comment: i have tried it outside but the node is declared inside the cuadrado() method. if i declare the node at the top then it does detect the touch and it goes for a second but then it comes back and crashes.

Comment: touchesBegan needs to be outside of your cuadrado func for it to work - if that gives you an error, post that error

Comment: It gives this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent: <SKSpriteNode> name:'(null)' texture:[<SKTexture> 'cuadradoRojo' (164 x 164)] position:{130.25773620605469, 790.66668701171875} size:{54.666667938232422, 54.666667938232422} rotation:0.00'
*** First throw call stack:
...
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)